# Use of powershell variables to change PC name and Doamain in command prompt

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file in order to change names and domain to new PCs.

The adding to the domain part is working fine, but the computer name part isn't

I am missing something in the use of the variable in `-NewName` as I get the error:

> NewName can not be null or empty.

If i run the commands directly in a powershell window, they work just fine.

```
:: Change Computer Name
powershell -command "$pcname = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the new PC name'"
powershell -command "Rename-Computer -NewName $pcname"

:: Add PC to the Domain
powershell -command "add-computer -domainname domain.name -Credential AD\admin.user"
```

---

Also, my initial plan for the naming of the pcs was a bit different.

For example all of the PCs are named in a way that they include the department and a number in the name.
So lets say that i have 2 departments: "Creative" and "Customer Support".
So PCs original name (i am restoring from a premade image) will be CSR and GFX accordingly.
So i need only to change the number!

I was trying to write a command which will combine the current name of the PC + the number that the user will enter when requested on the CMD window.
No luck to that part, and i think the issue was again the thing that i am missing, in how to use that variable inside a cmd script.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: The variable set in the first `powershell` command won't make it to the second `powershell` command. I cannot imagine *why* you would think that variables set in a script will then be available in another script. Try putting both the `Read-Host` and `Rename-Computer` in a single `powershell` command: `powershell -command "$pcname = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the new PC name'; Rename-Computer -NewName $pcname"`.

Comment: Why are you using a batch file to run powershell commands? Skip this intermediate step and just save your commands as a powershell script (.ps1 file) and then run it, either directly or via command line: `powershell -File C:\folder\script.ps1`...

Comment: AlexP, i wrote the command in this way, because i simply did not know which is correct way. That is why I asked here for help, since i could not really figure out what was wrong by myself. After a lot of searching i got lost at some point.

Thank you for the suggestion. I will try it out at Monday.

And James, i am using it because i want to implement that command in an other batch file that i have with a lot of functions.
Its 98% cmd and 2% powershell, so it is better for this case to add the command like this i think.

Answer (score 1):

[`Add-Computer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-computer) has a `NewName` parameter, so you can join the domain and rename the computer in a single command:

```
Add-Computer -DomainName domain.name -Credential AD\admin.user -NewName (Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the new PC name')
```

You can get the computers current name using the `$env:computername` variable, so combine this with `Read-Host` to prompt for the number and use this with the current name:

```
Add-Computer -DomainName domain.name -Credential AD\admin.user -NewName "$env:computername$(Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter PC Number')"
```

---

I would also remove the batch file from the process, powershell superseded batch and can do everything it can and way more.

Just save your commands in a plain-text file with the .ps1 extension. This is then a powershell script file and you can run it directly (right-click and choose 'run with powershell') or via command line if you're automating this process:

```
powershell -File C:\folder\script.ps1
```